# ng-class not updating outside the html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, ng-class, angularjs-ng-class

I have used following code in my project.
Sorry I won't be able to share any plunker or jsfiddle

```
    <div class="container full-height" ng-class="{'navmargin': model.showHeaderBasedError}" data-ui-view="main_container"></div>
{{model.showHeaderBasedError}}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

As the output state: the variable used outside the html is working perfectly fine but the one used in the Html is not updating.

Comment: what class are you trying to toggle with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-class` is incompatible with `ui-view`, You could fix this issuse by upgrading 
angular 1.3.8 and ui-router 0.2.13.

GitHub [**Issue Link**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/866) Here

**Update**

Try ng-attr directive that will help you.

```
ng-attr-class="{{model.showHeaderBasedError? 'navmargin': ''}"
```

Comment: If my class name is nav-top-margin then??

Comment: The thing is this variable is dynamic and might change depending upon the connection status. So in that case the variable updates but class attribute in HTML doesn't reflect the correct class

Comment: You can check the question for updated images. I have updated the angular and ui-router version. But it's still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84203/discussion-between-ayush-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: I have tried implementing the ng-style too. But the same issue persists there too..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this method with ng-class -

```
ng-class="{ 'nav-top-margin' : !model.showHeaderBasedError }"
```

Assuming `!model.showHeaderBasedError`  is a boolean, when it is true, that class will be there, if it's false it will not.

If you have multiple scenarios you can add multiple arguments to ng-class

```
 ng-class="{ 'nav-top-margin' : !model.showHeaderBasedError, 'class2' : expression2, 'class3' : expression3, 'class4' : expression4 }"
```

Comment: The thing is this variable is dynamic and might change depending upon the connection status. So in that case the variable updates but class attribute in HTML doesn't reflect the correct class

Comment: @Ayush you can add multiple arguments, if you can be more specific in what you mean i can answer that better. What variable is updating, and how is it suppose to reflect in the class (Change it to another class or ?)

Comment: What I wanted to say was, {{!model.showHeaderBasedError}} is reflecting correct value. But when I try to use the one you mentioned, the class attribute doesn't reflect the correct value.

Comment: @Ayush is  {{!model.showHeaderBasedError}} a boolean that you also want as a class?

Comment: Yes. So it may either be true or false. But is should come in the class attribute

Comment: I have updated the question as per your mentioned suggestion, still you can see the same issue

Comment: @ajmajmajma its an issue with `ng-class` and `ui-view`

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle with ui-router trying to help you. The boolean for model.showHeaderBasedError is updating the class inside the HTML.

https://jsfiddle.net/bbLqxdwx/2/

JS

```
angular.module('DemoApp', ['ui.router']).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
    $stateProvider.state('state1', {
        url: "/state1",
        views: {
            "main_container": {
                    templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
            }
        }
    }).state('state2', {
        url: "/state2",
        views: {
            "main_container": {
                template: "<b>State2</b>"
            }
        }
    });
}).controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        showHeaderBasedError: false
    };

    $scope.triggerError = function () {
        $scope.model.showHeaderBasedError = !$scope.model.showHeaderBasedError;
    };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="DemoApp">
<section data-ui-view="main_container"></section> <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
 <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/state1.html">
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        <div class="container full-height" ng-class = "{'navmargin': model.showHeaderBasedError}"> A message </div>
        {{model.showHeaderBasedError}}
        <button ng-click="triggerError()">Trigger Error</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Hope it helps.